# Placing tags around selected text in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, tags, highlighting

Is there a plugin, macro, or some sort of option for placing tags around selected text after I highlight and begin typing?

Comment: I've seen this basic functionality in Textmate repeatedly.

Comment: you can see my answer in this question :
http://superuser.com/questions/453235/notepad-highlight-text-and-insert-html-tag-tag-around-it/508467#508467

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes use the "Snippet Plus" Plugin. Then create your snippet and use the function "Surround with". It behaves like the Surround With of Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I was looking for something that actually works like Textmates, where you can just highlight the text and begin typing a tag and it auto surrounds it with said tag, rather than this which seems to need me to manually tell it I want to use surrond with.

Comment: @ReinSangeki that will be in direct conflict with the traditional behaviour of "Select and Overwrite", use a little the plugin that i'm mentionting. Maybe its all that you need.

Comment: Yeah I have been playing around with the plugin you've recommended. It's not perfect but it gets the job done. Thanks.

Comment: @ReinSangeki don't forget to mark as answer, :)

Comment: SnippetPlus can be downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/snippetplus/